# add comments to blog in mongodb nodejs

Tags: node.js, ajax, mongodb

i wanted to create a blog where people can comment on. I used ajax to send data to controller also received the data on the controller side. But the problem is the received data are not inserted into the database
i think the problem is in controller cause i have received data in controller
i'm new to nodejs your help would be highly appreicated!!

this is the data printed in the console
https://prnt.sc/11abe59

```
<form method="POST" onsubmit="return doComment(this);" class="theme-form-one">
    <input type="hidden" name="_id" value="{{blog._id}}">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6 col-12"><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"></div>
         <div class="col-12"><input type="email" name="email"  placeholder="Email"></div>
         <div class="col-12"><textarea name="comment" placeholder="Comments"></textarea></div>
      </div>
    <button class="theme-button-one">POST COMMENT</button>
</form>
```

this is my ajax file to send data to controller

```
<script>
    function doComment(form){
    $.ajax({
    url:"/blog/do-comment",
    method:"POST",
    data:{name:form.name.value,email:form.email.value,comment:form.comment.value,
        _id:form._id.value},
    success: function(response){
    alert(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
</script>
```

this is my controller

```
router.post("/do-comment",(req,res) =>{
    console.log(req.body)
       Blog.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.body._id},{Comment:{name:req.body.name,
        email:req.body.email,
        comment:req.body.comment},
         
           function(error,post){
              res.send("Comment Succssfully")
          }
       })
})
```

BlogSchema

```
var BlogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title:{
        type:String,
        required: "this field is required"
    },
    description:{
        type:String,
        required: "this field is required"
    },
    img:{
        type:String,
        required:"this filed is required"
    },
    comment:[
        {
            type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Comment'
        }
    ]
},{
    timestamps: true
    
})
```

commentSchema

```
var commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required: "this field is required"
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required: "this field is required"
    },
    comment:{
        type:String,
        required:"this filed is required"
    },
    blog:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Blog'
    }

},{
    timestamps: true
    
})
```

Comment: Please be clear on the probleme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you're not actually creating a new comment nor are you pushing new comments to the `comment` array, which is why the comment is not saved to the db. Change it to something like:

```
router.post("/do-comment", async (req,res) =>{      
    const comment = new Comment({name:req.body.name, email:req.body.email, comment:req.body.comment});
    await comment.save();
    await Blog.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.body._id}, {$push: {comment});
    res.send("Comment was added successfully");
})
```